# Open API Android Card Swiper with Payment Processing

Tags: android, payment, credit-card, payment-processing

I am looking for an Android compatible credit card swiper that comes with software which will process payments.  The software must have an open API so I can integrate it into my app.  Does anyone know of something that will do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is [Innerfence](http://www.innerfence.com/apps/credit-card-terminal/developer-api). Your can either use their sold-separately swiper, or enter the CC number manually.

Square had an open API, but from what I understand they abandoned it some months ago.

Comment: I looked at Square.  They don't offer any API support as of today.  I'll check out Innerfence

Comment: Unfortunately, Innerfence doesn't support Android tablets

Comment: Another option is PayAnywhere. According to [this press release](http://www.payanywhere.com/news-media-section/android-api-available-jun-4-2012.html), they have an Android SDK available. Their device list show several tablets, not sure how extensive you're looking for. I can't say for sure how well it fits your needs, because there's a bit of a shortage of information available without signing up on their website.

Comment: I put together a list for a similar question and added innerfence. Hopefully it will help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9323117/looking-for-library-or-sdk-for-scanning-credit-cards-from-my-android-application/

Answer (score 0):

try this: http://paypal.com/here

in Paypal's Profile | My Selling Tools | Instant Payment Notification (IPN) set a post-transaction callback URL that puts the transaction into your own database - Paypal will do a POST to your URL with everything they can share about the transaction (a lot).  Then program your app to request a query to that database.  My experience has been that the IPN callback happens within 2 seconds so it should take you a max of 4 seconds to query your own database from your app and get any (reasonable) answer you need about the transaction.

Doing it this way also keeps your PCI compliance profile/posture very low and you have few if any compliance responsibilities, unlike you would if your app actually saw the CC number or CVV.

Comment: Is there anyway to push transactions onto Paypal without using their app's interface?